# "Requested allocation is too large" error while running MIT Scheme on windows 7

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

Error:

"Requested allocation is too large.
Try with smaller argument to --heap"

I downloaded the windows binary from http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure why it does not work when I append --heap 512 at the end. But it works for me when I append it after mit-scheme.exe"

```
... mit-scheme.exe"  --heap 512 --library ...
```

Comment: I think it is related to http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?31710. Removing --edit on the shortcut made it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the link to the application and select properties. Edit the target:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin\mit-scheme.exe" --library "C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\lib" --edit
```

Add:

```
--heap 512
```

See also:
http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?31710

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't work as is on windows 10 64 bit, installed version 9.2. Removed --edit. now works well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new system variable called

```
MITSCHEME_HEAP_SIZE
```

and set its value to 512

Answer (score 0):

I had to update to 9.2 and add `--heap 512` after `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT-GNU Scheme\bin\mit-scheme.exe"`

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**

Remove "--edit" from "Target" Under "Properties" ~ Original Answer from [Irvin Denzel Torcuato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501318/irvin-denzel-torcuato)

**System / Settings**

OS: Windows 10